# How to get authorize and then get access token in Box API

Tags: c#-4.0, box-api, box, boxapiv2, box-view-api

How to get authorize and then get access token in Box API using Console or Library project in `C#`. I have tried authorize API but it returns HTML. I need only **THE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE** so that it can be passed into Token API for getting **access_token**.

Or can there be an enterprise **access_token** which is gotten through the web portal, just like developer token, but which never expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it By using call `oauth2/token` API, which returns `access_token` and `refresh_token`. `access_token` will expire as mentioned by @Jonh in above post. But you can store `refresh_token` in persistence storage. When `access_token` expires you can get new `access_token` by using `refresh_token` by calling same token API.

Answer (score 1):

Today I discovered that Box is making available a new service called 'Box for Developers' that enables server-to-server token grants and does not require end-user authentication. It's currently in beta. [Read more about it](https://box-content.readme.io/v2.0/docs/box-developer-edition).

The [BoxDevEditionHelper](https://github.com/cburnette/BoxDevEditionHelper-DotNet) package provides an implementation of the server-to-server OAuth workflow.

**Original Post**

> How to get authorize and then get access token in Box API using Console or Library project in C#.

OAuth2 requires the user to authenticate with the service in a browser or embedded browser window. There are no exceptions to this requirement.

> Or can there be an enterprise access_token which is gotten through the web portal, just like developer token, but which never expires?

No. All Box access tokens expire after ~60 minutes. Access tokens granted through the standard OAuth workflow can be indefinitely refreshed, but the tokens granted through the developer portal do not follow this workflow and thus cannot be refreshed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for response. Is there any solution that can work in Library/console project(without user/web interaction)?

Comment: Please see my edit -- there is a server-to-server token grant process available now.

Comment: That solution is fit for our requirements but i can not use it because it is in beta version. So, waiting for released version or some other workarounds.